# UILabel data to UIAlert issue in xcode 8, error

Tags: swift3, uilabel, xcode8, alert

I made an alert and I tried to follow a tutorial and put it into my code. I put the code in a few different places but the errors just kept getting worse. I finally just put it at the bottom, because thats where I ended up getting the fewest errors. I'm new to xcode so this very basic thing is very hard for me. Furthermore, I get errors all over the place when I put this in, and I have no idea how to fix this. Moreover, what I am trying to do is take the data that is being saved in my UILabel which is a name, and I want that to be shown up in the clickable part of the alert that "dismisses" the alert, but I have no idea how to do that or even get started when I can't add a basic alert into my code. Any help would be great source code even better. Sorry for all the questions. Thanks again in advance.

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity


class ViewController: UIViewController, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!

@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    output.text = input.text
    UserDefaults.standard.set(input.text, forKey: "MyName")
    input.text = ""
}

var currentPlayer:String!

var appDelegate:AppDelegate!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupPeerWithDisplayName(UIDevice.current.name)
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupSession()
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.advertiseSelf(true)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("peerChangedStateWithNotification:")), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidChangeStateNotification"), object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("handleReceivedDataWithNotification:")), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidReceiveDataNotification"), object: nil)
}

@IBAction func connect(_ sender: Any) {

    if appDelegate.MPCHandler.session != nil{
        appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupBrowser()
        appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.delegate = self

        self.present(appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}

func peerChangedStateWithNotification(notification:NSNotification){
    let userInfo = NSDictionary(dictionary: notification.userInfo!)

    let state = userInfo.object(forKey: "state") as! Int

    if state != MCSessionState.connecting.rawValue{
        self.navigationItem.title = "Connected"
    }

}

func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"myName") as?
        String
    {
        output.text = x
    }
}

}


 func viewDidAppear(_animated: Bool) {
createAlert(title: "HI", message: "ARE YOU READY")

}

 func createAlert (title: String, message:String)
{


let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "HI", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);))

    self.present(alert,animated: true, completion:nil)

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are most probably getting is **`Invalid redeclaration of 'viewDidAppear'`** means you are trying to add `viewDidAppear` method twice in your `ViewController`. So remove the below one method form your code and call `createAlert` inside the already exist `viewDidAppear` one.

Your second mistake is you forgot to add `}` for `UIAlertActionHandler` and there is no need to call `dismiss` on alert action it will automatically dismiss the alert.

You need to also change your selector syntax to Swift3 one and also you forgot to add `handleReceivedDataWithNotification` with your code.

Now with Swift use Swift native dictionary type instead of `NSDictionary`, so change your controller with below one to get your desired output.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!      

    var currentPlayer:String!

    var appDelegate:AppDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupPeerWithDisplayName(UIDevice.current.name)
        appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupSession()
        appDelegate.MPCHandler.advertiseSelf(true)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(peerChangedStateWithNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidChangeStateNotification"), object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleReceivedDataWithNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidReceiveDataNotification"), object: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func connect(_ sender: Any) {

        if appDelegate.MPCHandler.session != nil{
            appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupBrowser()
            appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.delegate = self

            self.present(appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
        output.text = input.text
        UserDefaults.standard.set(input.text, forKey: "MyName")
        input.text = ""
    }

    func peerChangedStateWithNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

        let state = userInfo["state"] as! Int

        if state != MCSessionState.connecting.rawValue{
            self.navigationItem.title = "Connected"
        }

    }

    func handleReceivedDataWithNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
        appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let x = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "myName") {
            output.text = x
        }
        else {
            output.text = "Default Name" //Set here default Name
        }
        self.createAlert(title: "HI", message: "ARE YOU READY")
    }

    func createAlert (title: String, message:String)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: output.text, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in

        }))
        self.present(alert,animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works thank you very much. I have one more question though
what does this mean..how do I do it. The controller you put with the answer seems to work fine?! so do I need to do the things you said below, if so how? sorry I am very new to xcode. Also thank you so much for all your help it really helped.

"You need to also change your selector syntax to Swift3 one and also you forgot to add handleReceivedDataWithNotification with your code.

Now with Swift use Swift native dictionary type instead of NSDictionary, so change your controller with below one to get your desired output."

Comment: @john Welcome mate :) What is the question here? Don't get your comment.

Comment: Thanks again. So what I am asking is how can make it to where whatever name is typed in my textbox (jim john, michael jake etc) is saved in my label. rn its "Default Name". Sorry I'm new to xcode and don't know how to do this. Also the Alert keeps popping up more than once when returning to the home screen after leaving it. How can I stop that so it only pops up once when a new player connects. Sorry for all the questions I just cant seem to figure these things out.

Comment: @john If you want to show popup once than call the method `createAlert` in `viewDidLoad` instead of  `viewDidAppear`. For  changing label text you can use textField delegate method didEndEditing search for it

Comment: .THANK YOU!. SoI put down what I did in a second answer under yours. I tried and camel cased the ' viewDidLoad ' and  'viewDidAppear ' but I keep getting errors I don't know what happened. I also tried putting in a didEndEditing so any user could put there name in and the text would save in the label. thus showing up in a popup but that gave me more issues so I took it out. I am also not sure where to put it exactly. It seems to interfere with the viewdidappear function. Sorry for all the issues I just want to get this correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity


class ViewController: UIViewController, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!

@IBAction func dick(_ sender: Any) {
    output.text = input.text
    UserDefaults.standard.set(input.text, forKey: "MyName")
    input.text = ""
}

var currentPlayer:String!

var appDelegate:AppDelegate!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupPeerWithDisplayName(UIDevice.current.name)
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupSession()
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.advertiseSelf(true)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.peerChangedStateWithNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidChangeStateNotification"), object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.handleReceivedDataWithNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidReceiveDataNotification"), object: nil)
}

@IBAction func connect(_ sender: Any) {

    if appDelegate.MPCHandler.session != nil{
        appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupBrowser()
        appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.delegate = self

        self.present(appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}

@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    output.text = input.text
    UserDefaults.standard.set(input.text, forKey: "MyName")
    input.text = ""
}

func peerChangedStateWithNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let state = userInfo["state"] as! Int

    if state != MCSessionState.connecting.rawValue{
        self.navigationItem.title = "Connected"
    }

}

func handleReceivedDataWithNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    print(userInfo)
}

func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
*func viewdidloadOverride; func viewDidAppear*(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let x = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "myName") {
        output.text = x
    }
    else {
        output.text = "x" //Set here default Name
    }
    self.createAlert(title: "HI", message: "ARE YOU READY")
}

func createAlert (title: String, message:String)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: output.text, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in

    }))
    self.present(alert,animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

}